# How to create a solfege instrument in Logic Pro X?

Tags: midi, logic-pro

I'd like to create a midi instrument with a human voice of fixed-do solfege in Logic Pro X, for example, whenever I hit a C on the midi controller, I'd like it to make a "do" sound. How can I do this?

Comment: Did you ever create or find such an instrument? If so could you share?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have at least two options:

1. **Find a VST/AU instrument** that includes those sounds. There are plenty of vocal synths but I don't personally know of any that do "fixed-do" as opposed just "oohs" and "aahs". I wouldn't be surprised if one exists though.
2. **Create your own with EXS24**. So, in other words you'd record yourself or somebody else singing through the range of solfege syllables that you'd like to use. Then you'd create a custom EXS24 (Logic's sampler) instrument using those audio file(s). [[tutorial]](https://9to5mac.com/2015/07/12/logic-pros-how-to-sampler-instruments-exs24/) [[vids]](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=exs24%20custom%20instrument)